# Kubernetes: Docker pod starting fails except one

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We are running a Jetty service on the Google container engine. This one service runs just fine in a pod with a rc. We can shut it down, rebuild it and do all manner of things to it and it will still work.

Now we want to extend our infrastructure with a debian image that runs something else.
Locally, the docker works fine and we can access the debian commandline. Once we try to run the pod in the cloud, we get issues.

The Dockerfile we use contains: FROM debian:latest
Then we run the next commands:

```
docker build -t eu.gcr.io/project_id/debstable:stable .

gcloud docker push eu.gcr.io/project_id/debstable:stable

kubectl run debstable --image=eu.gcr.io/project_id/debstable:stable
```

The pod receives the CrashLoopBackOff STATUS and keeps on restarting.
Part of the logs show this:

```
I0120 14:19:58.438979    3479 kubelet.go:2012] SyncLoop (ADD): "debstable-blvdi_default"
I0120 14:19:58.478235    3479 manager.go:1707] Need to restart pod infra container for "debstable-blvdi_default" because it is not found
I0120 14:20:00.025467    3479 server.go:944] GET /stats/default/debstable-blvdi/e2ab2ffc-bf80-11e5-a1d8-42010af001a5/debstable: (100.384µs) 404 [[Go 1.1 package http] 10.0.0.3:40650]
I0120 14:20:05.017006    3479 server.go:944] GET /stats/default/debstable-blvdi/e2ab2ffc-bf80-11e5-a1d8-42010af001a5/debstable: (56.159µs) 404 [[Go 1.1 package http] 10.0.0.3:40694]
I0120 14:20:10.015072    3479 server.go:944] GET /stats/default/debstable-blvdi/e2ab2ffc-bf80-11e5-a1d8-42010af001a5/debstable: (66.802µs) 404 [[Go 1.1 package http] 10.0.0.3:40708]
I0120 14:20:15.017521    3479 server.go:944] GET /stats/default/debstable-blvdi/e2ab2ffc-bf80-11e5-a1d8-42010af001a5/debstable: (32.91µs) 404 [[Go 1.1 package http] 10.0.0.3:40566]
I0120 14:20:18.530030    3479 manager.go:2022] Back-off 10s restarting failed container=debstable pod=debstable-blvdi_default
```

The docker info shows the versions, which may be relevant:

```
$ sudo docker info
Containers: 24
Images: 68
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 116
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.625 GiB

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Thanks and good day

Comment: kubectl run will create an rc+pod with your image as one container. It will not guess a command to run in the container, so eg: something like `kubectl run ubuntu --image=ubuntu:14.04` will enter a crashloop, because the container will keep exiting but it has a restart policy asking for restarts. If you have a command, you can specify `kubectl run --image=foo -i cmd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prashanth B was right! Having no commands causes the pod to restart in the crashloop.

Thanks and good day.